# WinXP Scheduled Task: Open a webpage in a browser

Tags: windows-xp, website, login, scheduled-tasks

**I am trying to create a scheduled task that opens up a webpage that has requires credentials for an http login dialog.**  I can get IE to load the page, but it will not remember my password for some reason. Firefox *does* remember my password,  But it still requires someone sitting at the machine to click OK.  Also, the scheduled task will not even run if Firefox is already running even though I specify 'new window' as a command line argument. Instead, it gives this message: *'Firefox is allready running, but not responding. To open a new window...'*).  Here is the command I'm using to load the page:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-window http://example.com/
```

Idealy, this is what I need:

1. Load a URL into a new browser window
2. Login to a http username/password dialog

**Thats it, seems simple right?  How should i be doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using a different scheduler to see if it can get around the issue of FF not opening a second window. I use [System Scheduler](http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm), which I've found "better" than the built in.

For OKing the passsword, can FF remember to stay logged in? Depends on your private data settings- make sure to disable "clear private data" on exit.

A bit clumsy perhaps, but a simple autohotkey script can send <kbd>enter</kbd>, perhaps add this action to the schedule.

Comment: Armitage- glad I could help. Which suggestion did the job?

Comment: That worked almost perfectly.  This program has keystroke options, where I can tell it to type in the login/password. Not ideal for these sensitive credentials.  Also, this program doesn't seem to have options to 'wake' the computer.  I actually would like this to run in the middle of the night as a WinXP service. It looks like only the pro version of this software will allow that.  Oh well, beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: Try this to wake: http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/download.php?what=WOSB

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to get firefox open, you can use the [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863) addon to login for you.